# Activity preview disappears when I add a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

[A screenshot of the activity.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksZDr.png)

The dependencies i have added are the following:

```
implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.5")
implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.5")
```

I have tried to invalidate the cache, but that did not work.
I basically followed android documentation

[Requested error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CNqW.png)

Comment: Also i have tried to "Force Refresh Layout" but that did not work as well

Comment: could you press the red icon in the corner of you photo? (above the blue question mark) (I think It was with an exclamation mark) It will show the current errors within the xml file (update the question with the results please)

Comment: Can you post the errors that the Buttons are giving?

Comment: I posted the error!